# Warning when font lacks symbol

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I have a document with

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

With lualatex from TeXLive 2014, `$\mathbf{\chi}$` typesets a nice bold χ. With TeXLive 2015, the area where the character should be is just blank. I realize that bold greek symbols is not necessarily a simple thing, but **is there any way I can realize something like this has happened?**

It seems scary that a single symbol possibly buried in hundreds of pages can just go blank from one TeX version to another, without warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol is not gone, but the interface of unicode-math has changed a bit.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
mathbf: $\mathbf{\chi}$
symbf:  $\symbf{\chi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The log-file warns you about missing chars:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D712) in font "TeXGyrePagella/B:mode=bas
e;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;"!
```

Comment: This is embarassing: I *case-sensitively* grepped the log file for "missing". I'm an idiot. Thank you, this both answers my question and solves my problem :)